# Determine whether Date is in the past?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, compare

What is the best way to determine whether a `Date` is in the past?

Currently I have:

```
If MyDate < Date.Now
```

Comment: In which time-zone? The local timezone? A data doesn't have a clear start/end instant, unless you specify a timezone.

Comment: @MitchWheat: is there an expectation to up-vote?

Comment: Yes, there is. If people help you, and presumably with that many questions, many people have given their time to help you. I notice that you haven't upvoted any of the answers below either.

Comment: @MitchWheat: is that stipulated anywhere?  How am I meant to know I should up-vote if it isn't part of any rules/guidelines?

Comment: I believe it is taken to be common sense: people freely help you, you give them something free in return.

Answer (score 1):

What you've got is a reasonable *starting* point, but there are lots of other considerations to think about:

- Assuming `MyDate` is a `DateTime`, you really need to consider its [`Kind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind.aspx). For example, if the kind is UTC, you should probably be using [`DateTime.UtcNow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow.aspx). If the kind is Local, it's fine to use `DateTime.Now`. If it's Unspecified, then you're in a bit of a quandry, as it's unclear exactly what it means
- Your question talks about a "date" - is the value really only meant to represent a date, or a date and time? If it's meant to be just a date, you probably want `Today` instead of `Now`, or `UtcNow.Date` for the UTC version.
- Do you need to take time zones into account? Might you perhaps be better using `DateTimeOffset`? It really depends on the source of your data and the *exact* meaning you want to attach.

(As an aside, a lot of these issues would be more transparent if you were using a date/time API which separated different kinds of values into different types. It so happens I'm working on such an API - [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) :)

Comment: In VB.NET it seems `Date` and `DateTime` are interchangeable?

Comment: @CJ7: Yes, I believe `Date` is an alias for `DateTime`. You still need to think about what you actually want :)

Answer (score 0):

if  DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, MyDate , Date.Now) < 0

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are working in the same time zone.

Here is a little code snippet to show how this can be done:

```
Dim MyDate As Date = #11/4/2012#
Dim ts As TimeSpan = MyDate.Subtract(Today)
If ts.TotalDays < 0 Then
  MsgBox("MyDate is in the past")
ElseIf ts.TotalDays > 0 Then
  MsgBox("MyDate is in the future")
Else
  MsgBox("MyDate is today")
End If
```